# Rate of change of filling water into a cup

Tags: calculus

If I have a cup that being filled at constant rate of 20cc a second and the radius of the bottom of the cup is 2cm, the radius at the top is 4cm and the height of the cup is 6cm. At what rate the water rise when the cup is half full?

I should start by drawing an extension to the cup and making it a cone.

I think that if I define $\ x$ as the distance from the bottom of the cup to the bottom of the cone then using similar triangles $\ \frac{6+x}{2} = \frac{x}{1} $ and so $\ x = 6 $ so the height of the whole cone is $\ 12 $ (?) and from here I don't know what to do next.

Comment: What does "half full" mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need calculus here, though I'll use the notation.

At a height $h$ above the bottom of the cup, the radius of the cup is $r=2+\frac{h}{3}$. When the cup is half full, $h=3$ and so $r=3$. The area of the circle at this height is $A=\pi r^2 = 9\pi$. The momentary rise rate $\frac{dh}{dt}$ at this height is just the flow rate $\frac{dV}{dt}$ into the cup divided by the circle area or $$\frac{dh}{dt} = \frac{\frac{dV}{dt}}{A}= \frac{20}{9\pi} \frac{\text{cm}}{\text{s}}$$